# Google Maps v3 api problems

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My mission is to create a Google map, loaded from Google Maps Engine. Which of course has all the necessary data like: name, description (address), Latitude and longitude in it.

Until now, I've loaded the mapId successfully as well as the layerKey - But the data from the map doesn't show.

Here is what I have so far:

Wordpress/Frontend:

```
<section id="become-volunteer" class="section-padding">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 become-volunteer-wrap">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3>Indleveringssteder</h3>
                        <form id="contributersform" action="" method="post" onclick"seachLocations(2)" onsubmit="return false;">
                            <input type="text" class="controls" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Find nærmeste - indtast by/område" />
                            <span class="search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                        </form>
                        <p>På kortet til højre ser du en oversigt over de indleveringssteder, hvor du kan indlevere dine dåseringe. Nedenfor har mulighed for at tilmelde dig som indsamler fra lokalområdet. </p>
                        <div class="volunteer-cta"> 
                            <p>Vil du tage imod dåseringe?</p>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="signup-btn" data-toggle="modal" class="signup-volunteer-btn"><span class="contributer-collector-icon"></span>Meld dig som indsamler</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="volunteer-map"></div>
</section>
```

Map.js:

```
function initializeMap() {

    var map;

    var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.348995,9.988174),
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            scrollwheel: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('volunteer-map'), mapOptions);

    var mapsEngineLayer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
        mapId: '01841796515013443231-16071188762309719429',
        layerKey: '01841796515013443231-08112974690991164587',
        map: map,
        clickable: true,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
    });


}   
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

Comment: At the first link, I don't see a map. You could take screenshots and copy them into your question so that this question retains any value if your links become obsolete. Also, please state exactly what the problem is. In other words: What is it that's not working with what you have so far?

Comment: Sry but I don't really understand what you want to do. Could you ask a more specific question?

Comment: You might investigate the javascript errors: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'getKey' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry about that cfi:
What's not working sofar is, that the markers with their icons doesn't show up, as expected from the Google Maps Engine map.

Comment: @cfi: your crystal ball was working a year ago! Just removed two dead links. Am voting to close as unreproduceable.

Answer (score 1):

Use your console:[image]

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

Comment: Thanks for the note Adam!
- I've now deactivated the WP Google Maps plugin, and deleted the other wp_enqueue's I had in my functions.php file - so it now looks like this:
http://cl.ly/image/2y1U3O3B2a0g

Comment: @cfi this is what I'm getting now on my homepage: http://cl.ly/image/2q0b1D2j3g0t

But the result should be: http://cl.ly/image/0b3g0S050732